# Dynamic TForm creation Idiosyncrasies(bugs?) in Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

This one is driving me up a wall.  Most of the conversion from Delphi 6 to XE5 is proceeding smoothly, but I have various routines to dynamically build various TForm descendents (NO DFM), pop it up and generally return a value.  I have a number of them that work fine in D6.  Generally, I choose a place I want to pop something up (like over a panel), and what I want to popup (editbox, memo, listbox...).  I create the form, set initial values and call showmodal and return some result.

The same code, compiled in XE5 has execution (glitches).  One is that the created form accepts left,top and such, but does NOT display itself there.  The values are correctly in the properties, but the form is in the wrong place.  A second, probably related (glitch) is that when I create a TMemo or TListbox and store some text in it, "ShowModal" displays the data properly, but "Show" does not.

It has taken me several hours to digest the problem down to its simplest form, removing virtual all of my personal code.  AS SHOWN HERE, IT WORKS PERFECTLY

If I comment out this line, it does not work - the form is displayed in the wrong place

```
XX.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));      // EXTREMELY WEIRD PATCH
```

This line is a function call which OUGHT NOT affect anything else, and I don't use the returned value.

The commented out "Show" line demonstrates the other problem (data not being displayed).

I have tried `Application.ProcessMessages` in all sorts of places, but it never makes things better, and at times make things worse.

Color me "puzzled".

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type TMemoForm = class(TForm)
   private
   public
      XMemo         : TMemo;
   end;


Function  PopUpMemoStr(txt : AnsiString; x : integer = 200; y : integer = 200; w : integer = 400 ; h : integer = 400 ) : AnsiString;  // more or less a dummy for testing on XE5 2/28/14
var XX : TMemoForm;
     begin
     XX := TMemoForm.CreateNew(Application);

     XX.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));      // *** EXTREMELY WEIRD FIX ***
     XX.Left := X; XX.Top := Y; XX.Width := w;  XX.height := h;
     XX.caption := 'Dummy PopUpMemo';

     XX.XMemo := TMemo.create(XX);
     XX.XMemo.parent := XX;
     XX.XMemo.align := alClient;
     XX.XMemo.text := txt;

     //logit('PopUpMemoStr R='+TRectToStr(MyGetScreenRect(XX)));
     XX.showmodal;
     //XX.show; delay(3.00);  // other "no data" problem
     XX.free;
     end;

//exercise code -- Panel2 is just a visible spot to see if positioning works correctly 
var s : AnsiString;
var R : TRect;
     begin
     //R := MyGetScreenRect(Panel2);                    
     R := Rect(414,514,678,642);        // just a useful screen location for testing
     s := 'One'+CRLF+'Two'+CRLF+'Three'+CRLF+'Four';    // "CRLF is #13#10
     PopUpMemoStr(s,R.Left,R.Top,R.Right-R.Left,R.Bottom-R.Top);


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the form positioning problem, you need to set the form's `Position` to `poDesigned`.

For your second problem, you can't delay like that. You are not giving the Form a chance to process messages. Changing it to something like the code below displays the data correctly (although you really should not be doing this sort of thing either):

```
begin
  XX := TMemoForm.CreateNew(nil);
  try
    XX.Position := poDesigned; // This line needs to be added for the positioning
    XX.SetBounds(X, Y, w, h);
    XX.Caption := 'Dummy PopUpMemo';

    XX.XMemo := TMemo.Create(XX);
    XX.XMemo.Parent := XX;
    XX.XMemo.Align := alClient;
    XX.XMemo.Text := txt;

    //logit('PopUpMemoStr R='+TRectToStr(MyGetScreenRect(XX)));
    // XX.ShowModal;
    // This displays the data correctly but is not advisable
    XX.Show;
    for I := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      Sleep(500);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  finally
    XX.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to use `Show()` for a Form like that, you should use the Form's `OnClose` event and set its `Action` parameter to `caFree` and just do the `Show()` in your code. Put a timer on the Form for x seconds and `Close()` it when the timer finishes. A bit like this:

```
type
  TMemoForm = class(TForm)
  public
     XMemo : TMemo;
     XTimer: TTimer;
     procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
     procedure TimerElapsed(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TMemoForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TMemoForm.TimerElapsed(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

```
begin
  XX := TMemoForm.CreateNew(nil);
  try
    XX.Position := poDesigned; // This line needs to be added for the positioning
    XX.SetBounds(X, Y, w, h);
    XX.Caption := 'Dummy PopUpMemo';
    XX.OnClose := XX.FormClose;

    XX.XMemo := TMemo.Create(XX);
    XX.XMemo.Parent := XX;
    XX.XMemo.Align := alClient;
    XX.XMemo.Text := txt;

    XX.XTimer := TTimer.Create(XX);
    XX.XTimer.Interval := 3000;
    XX.XTimer.OnTimer := XX.TimerElapsed;
    XX.Active := True;

    XX.Show; // Just show the form. The rest is in the Form itself.
  except
    XX.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The rule of thumb about using `Show()` vs `ShowModal()` is that if you need to show the Form and wait for it to close, use `ShowModal()` (which pumps the message queue internally for you), otherwise use `Show()` instead and let the VCL deal with the normal message loop for you.

Comment: If you need to loop manually, DO NOT blindly call `Application.ProcessMessages()`! Use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931008.aspx) or [`GetQueueState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644940.aspx) to check for pending messages BEFORE THEN calling `Application.ProcessMessages()`. If you need to wait for a time period to elapse, a combination of [`CreateWaitableTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681985.aspx) and `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` works well for that.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  I see that TForm.Position is a property in Delphi 6, but it must default differently, because I had never seen this behavior before.  The Show/ShowModal was never intended to be good code, I was just trying to clarify the position problem and that appeared to be a quicker way to cycle through test runs.  In retrospect, it is a "Well, Duh!" - the memo never got the message to refresh itself before thw whole test was over, and the form freed.

Answer (score 1):

Your extremely weird patch, calling `ClientToScreen` on the newly created form, should fix the issue as it does, even if you don't use the point that's returned.

In the case when you don't use it, when you set your form's bounds, since the window of the form has not yet been created, the VCL keeps this information to be later passed to the API when the window is about to be shown. But this information will be discarded since VCL also tells the API to use default window position because of the `poDefaultPosOnly` setting of `Position` property.

In the case when you use it, to be able to determine the position of the form in the screen the VCL first creates the window of the form. Hence when you later set the bounds of the form, they are actually implemented through `SetWindowPos`.

As such, if you've used

```
XX.HandleNeeded;
```

instead of

```
XX.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));
```

it would be a more direct workaround.

Of course the correct solution is in Graymatter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105093/243614).

I cannot comment on `Show` not displaying data, the code you posted in the question should not exhibit that kind of behavior.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  In my original code, there were several layers of my own control modification routines, and I just started simplifying and removing them line by line until the form stopped getting positioned correctly.  XX.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0)) was the last line standing.  Your explanation makes it much clearer why it had the effect it did.  Thanks.

Comment: @HNR - You're welcome. I had to make a little correction in the answer. BTW, you're right about the default being changed, I checked D7 and default is `poDesigned` there.

Comment: it may be more subtle than a change in default, because the only setting that gets the behavior I want is explicitly setting the position property to poDesigned. The others get rational results (poScreenCenter...), but poDesigned seems to let me set the position properties and get the expected results. This is not precisely what I would have expected by reading the Help definitions of each of the values.  "poDesigned" may link to a dfm, and there is no dfm in this case. It may be that the act of setting it is what makes the difference - very much like the effect of ClientToScreen.

Comment: Yes, XX.HandleNeeded works, and it makes more sense than the Position property.  I have coded in Delphi for many, many years, but I have tended to ignore areas where I wasn't having any problems.  Runtime form creation has always worked just fine, but now I'm starting to see some of the subtleties I was missing.

Comment: @HNR - The [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.Position) just mean that the form will use whatever position you assign it to. Don't put too much thought into "design time" that's referred. I'd favor 'poDesigned' to 'HandleNeeded', it lets the window to be created when it is to be shown, and creating an early handle may cause some problems with some corner cases.